# How to calculate vector potential of swirly vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

Examine whether $b: \mathbb R ^3 → \mathbb R^3 $ is a vortex field and determine a vector potential $a$.

$b=\begin{pmatrix} 4x^4y^3z^2-3x^4z^2 \\ -4x^3y^4z^2 \\ 4z^3x^3 \end{pmatrix} $

$a=?$

Hint: Take $a_1$ as $0$.

My idea:

I calculated $curl$ $b$ and because of the fact that $curl$ $b$ $\neq0$ I came to the conclusion that this vector field is "swirly" (vortex field).

Is this correct?

How do I calculate vector potential of this vector field? I found in the book that vector potential is equal the gradient when the vector field is not swirly. But here it is, and how to calculate it in this case?

Comment: I have a hard time finding the definition of "swirly" or "vortex field" anywhere. Does having nonzero curl really make sense? I think the vector field $(xy, 0,0)$ has nonzero curl all over the place, but it is not very swirly looking...

Comment: I am translating it from another language, and that is the best translation I could find. I translated "wirbelfeld" (on german) as "swirly"..Maybe someone will know now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of the vector potential (given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential) $a$ is the vector potential of $b$ if

$$b=\nabla \times  a.$$

Then

$$a(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
x^4z^3\\
x^4y^4z^2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Indeed,

$$b=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
\end{bmatrix} \times\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
x^4z^3\\
x^4y^4z^2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
i&j&k\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
0&x^4z^3&x^4y^4z^2
\end{vmatrix}=
$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
4x^4y^3z^2-3x^4z^2\\
-4x^3y^4z^2\\
4x^3z^3
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: But how excatly you found $a$ ?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic: First, I denoted the unknown components of $a$ by $X,Y,Z$ and did the vector product. I found that, for example, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}Z$ has to equal $4x^4y^3z^2$. From here $Z$ turned out to be $x^4y^4z^2+const.$ And so on.
Perhaps I should have added the constants as well.